# Conversion of energy of rifle and bullet

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, projectile

If we shoot a bullet from a rifle,do the energy we put on the rifle=rifle's backward kinetic energy+bullet's kinetic energy and sound energy(the noise from the shooting)+heat energy(if the rifle's metal is hot)same?=the whole conversion cycle of energy from it?(to be precise)

Comment: Not sure if this is clear to you - all the energy comes from the chemical reaction of the powder in the casing. Which is maybe what you phrased as "the energy we put on the rifle". And then there's a second equality in the end "the whole conversion cycle of energy from it" and I don't understand what you mean by that. But anyway yes. The chemical energy released by the burning powder exactly equals the sum of energies you described. It's a pretty complete list of where the energy goes, but by far most of the energy goes to heat and the bullet's kinetic energy.

Answer (score 0):

The chemical energy of propellent goes into the KE of the bullet, the KE of the muzzle-blast gas, the increase of internal energy of that hot gas, the recoil KE of the rifle,  and the hot barrel. The "bang" noise is extracted from the KE and internal energy of the combusion gas which eventually is at rest and at ambient temperature..